# How do I register an exception handler for socket errors in CherryPy?

Tags: python, sockets, http, tcp, cherrypy

Suppose I have the following application:

```
import cherrypy

class HelloWorld(object):
    def my_handler(self, a):
        assert a == "foo"

    def index(self, a):
        # Register parameter a/my_handler/...
        return "A" * 100000
    index.exposed = True

cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld())
```

And the following client:

```
import httplib

h = httplib.HTTPConnection('localhost', 8080)
h.request("GET", "/?a=foo")
r = h.getresponse(True)
print r.read(10)
```

I would like to deal explicitly with the case where a client tears down the connection (either politely or not) and thus hasn't received the response. So, in this example, `my_handler` should be called because the `GET` response wasn't delivered before the connection closed.

The CherryPy documentation refers to errors that are a bit higher up the TCP stack than I'm aiming for (c.f. [cperror](http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/3.3.0/refman/_cperror.html), [cprequest](https://cherrypy.readthedocs.io/en/3.3.0/refman/_cprequest.html)'s error_response). I dug through some of the CherryPy source, and is some mention of socket errors [in e.g. read_request_line and simple response](https://github.com/cherrypy/cherrypy/blob/master/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py). It is unclear to me whether these are exposed anywhere and, more importantly, if there is a canonical way to hook.

Why, you might ask, would I be interested in such a thing? There's a slight abuse of HTTP semantics and it's important to verify that a GET response was delivered; otherwise some accounting needs to be done.

Comment: Slightly modified code-snippet straight from the cherrypy website, incredibly broad question. I'm a bit baffled ... What is this supposed to be? I am under the impression you want to spare yourself from reading the documentation.

Comment: I've added a client-side example and an assert in the handler, as well as portions of the documentation I've found most relevant.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it looks you could catch/inspect some HTTP response state from `on_end_request` hook: http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/extend.html?highlight=hooks#hook-point